# eclipse neon.1 jonas 5 server adapter

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, configuration, jst, jonas

I am running **eclipse neon.1** under **ubuntu 16.04**. I installed eclipse using eclipse installer and installed the Java EE package. I installed jonas and maven and such so everything is set up. I can build my project.

However I can't find a way to integrate my jonas server within eclipse using the jope adapter http://forge.ow2.org/projects/jope/

I did download the latest version 5.1.0 extracted it in the dropins folder but it seems that eclipse ignore it. So i can't add my jonas server in my eclipse environment.

Here's a log of the startup of my eclipse instance :

```
./eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug ./.options 
Start VM: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 47000e
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-clean
-console
-consoleLog
-debug ./.options
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar 
Install location:
    file:/opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon/
Configuration file:
    file:/opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
  eclipse.properties not found
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.0.v201605131737.jar
  eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
    file:/home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/
    file:/home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
    file:/home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.0.v201605131737.jar
Splash location:
    /home/tvba5179/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1.v20160907-1200/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/opt/eclipse-user/jee-neon/./.options loaded
Time to load bundles: 36
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 3498
osgi> org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/tvba5179/Documents/Build/workspaces/eclipse/newcare-tdb/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.7.0.20160603-1933.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://953.fwk540159270:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://953.fwk540159270:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Application Started: 7691
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountred the same problem and i resolved it by installing the plugin with the eclipse GUI. Just click on Help -> Install new software -> Add a repository:

Name : Jonas

Location : http://jope.ow2.org/update/jope/

Then select JOnAS Server Adapter and install it.